# How to have an asymmetrical texture on a mirror modifier model?

Tags: texturing, modifiers, uv

I am making a low poly human model and i want to texture its face but it is always symmetrical and I don't want it to be.

Comment: Can you add more info about your model? For example, is there a mirror modifier on your model?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly what you want, enable the *Data > Mirror U* and *Mirror V* of your *Mirror* modifier:

[image]